# Matching Primary key with url in Django. When I am trying to enter the url: (localhost:8000/detail/S1111111A/) it always shows a mismatch error

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-rest-framework

*Below is my view, url and model. I have stored some values in my database, and I make patientNRIC as the primary key, now I wanted to access the respective patient details through their patientNRIC, however, I could not do that, it always show me the error of mismatch. plss helllpp meeeee. Thanks*

**#view.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .models import PatientDetail
from .serializer import PatientSerializer

# Create your views here.


@api_view(['Get', 'POST'])
# @csrf_exempt
def patient_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        patientdetails = PatientDetail.objects.all()

        # serialization
        serializer = PatientSerializer(patientdetails, many=True)
        # return Json
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        #data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = PatientSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@api_view(['Get', 'PUT','DELETE'])
@csrf_exempt
def patient_detail(request,patientNRIC):
    try:
        patientdetails = PatientDetail.objects.get(patientNRIC)

    except PatientDetail.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == "GET":

        # serialization, getting one data only
        serializer = PatientSerializer(patientdetails)
        # return Json
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == "PUT":
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = PatientSerializer(patientdetails, data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        patientdetails.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

**#url.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import patient_list, patient_detail


urlpatterns = [
    path('patient/', patient_list),
    path(r'detail/^[STFG]\d{7}[A-JZ]$/', patient_detail),

    # re_path('detail/<int:pk>/', patient_detail)


]
```

**#model.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.


class PatientDetail(models.Model):

    patientName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    patientNRIC = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    patientAddress = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    patientAllergies = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    patientMedicationName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dosage = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sideEffects = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.patientName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Nothing can match the pattern `r'detail/^[STFG]\d{7}[A-JZ]$/'` because `^` means the string should start at this point yet you have `detail/` before it and `$` means the string should end at this point, yet you have a `/` after it. This doesn't make sense and is a contradiction.
2. You aren't even capturing these arguments to pass them to the view.
3. You write this pattern in the `path` function which **doesn't** use regex, instead you either want to use a custom path converter or use `re_path`. See [Using regular expressions [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions)

Change your patterns like so:

```py
from django.urls import path, re_path
from .views import patient_list, patient_detail


urlpatterns = [
    path('patient/', patient_list),
    re_path(r'^detail/(?P<patientNRIC>[STFG]\d{7}[A-JZ])/$', patient_detail),
]
```

Next in your view specify the parameter `patientNRIC` as a keyword argument instead of a positional one:

```
patientdetails = PatientDetail.objects.get(patientNRIC=patientNRIC)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `patient_detail` view I think you should get objects like this
`patientdetails = PatientDetail.objects.get(patientNRIC = patientNRIC)`